# .delay divA, when show DivA, auto hide DivB

Tags: jquery, css, animation, html

does there have any code, if i set the .delay(500) show divA, then when divA show, divB will be auto hide when detect divA are appear. Because for my visual design, DivA and DivB will be the same place. i can't use too much on the .delay for the page, because i scared of the timer problem, because not everyone has the good internet access.

Did there any way to do that? because i not that expert on the animation part, so i use gif animation to proceed.

my visual flow explaine:
1st thing will show a big paper-roll (it's close), when i click on the paper-roll, it will scale small and then will move to the left side, and then the next frame will be roll out the paper-roll form left to right.

:((

Comment: Just to clarify.. you want divB to show when divA has FINISHED loading, or you want divB to show when divA STARTS loading?

Comment: i need divA has finish only show divB :)

Comment: Glad I helped - 'Up-vote' my answer as well if you found it useful, good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a callback function with things like this to detect when the first thing has finished it's intended operation...

```
$('#divA').delay(500).fadeIn('slow', function() {
    // divA has finished loading.. NEXT.
    $('#divB').hide();
});
```

And you can continue with things like `fadeOut()` and more...

```
$('#divB').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    // Oh look, divB has just faded out!
});
```

---

So finally, if you have `#divA` set to hidden, and `#divB` visible, `#divA` fades in and when it has finished fading in, `#divB` fades out.

Of course, you can switch

`.fadeIn('slow', function() . . .` to `.show(function() ...` instead if you don't want the fade animations.

---

Your final code, according to your question:

```
<div id="divA" style="display:none">
    divA
</div>
<div id="divB">
    divB
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#divA').delay(500).fadeIn('slow', function() {
        // divA has finished loading.. NEXT.
        $('#divB').fadeOut('slow');
    });
</script>
```